# Problems when deploying a REST service with JBoss

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, jboss, war

I had to create a REST service and to deploy it on a JBoss server.
For now it just response with "hello" strings to whatever POST request comes (I just need to test if at least this works).

For technical constraints I had to use jdk 1.7.
It is coded in Java, with Maven, and using Spring MVC.

The code, for as much as I'm ignorant about, should work. The war it is deployed succesfully and according to jboss' log I suppose it is mapping the resources as I expect. The problem is that when I send a POST request to what I expect to be the URI (*X.X.X.X:8080/sduca/OSSreceiver*), the resource is not found.

I really can't find why or how. I premise I never did such a thing but according to coworkers it should work. What could possibly be a cause? Did I miss something?

Sorry If I put the entire project (I hate who does it) but I think it is necessary because every line I type could be idiotic.

**Thanks anyway! :)**

The response I get

```
JBWEB000065: HTTP Status 404 - /sduca/OSSreceiver

JBWEB000309: type JBWEB000067: Status report

JBWEB000068: message /sduca/OSSreceiver

JBWEB000069: description JBWEB000124: The requested resource is not available.
```

Here there is the log written when I deploy:

```
[0m[0m15:12:53,106 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS015009: Scan found incompletely copied file content for deployment /opt/UTM/jboss/standalone/deployments/sduca-consumer-listener-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war. Deployment changes will not be processed until all content is complete.
[0m[0m15:13:02,076 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "sduca-consumer-listener-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war" (runtime-name: "sduca-consumer-listener-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war")
[0m[33m15:13:02,888 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-11) JBAS011006: Not installing optional component org.springframework.http.server.ServletServerHttpAsyncRequestControl due to an exception (enable DEBUG log level to see the cause)
[0m[33m15:13:02,889 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-11) JBAS011006: Not installing optional component org.springframework.web.context.request.async.StandardServletAsyncWebRequest due to an exception (enable DEBUG log level to see the cause)
[0m[0m15:13:02,926 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 219) JBAS018210: Register web context: /sduca
[0m[0m15:13:02,945 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/sduca]] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 219) 1 Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath
[0m[0m15:13:03,005 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/sduca]] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 219) Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
[0m[0m15:13:03,006 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 219) Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
[0m[0m15:13:03,024 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 219) Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Thu Aug 30 15:13:03 CEST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
[0m[0m15:13:03,100 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 219) Registering annotated classes: [class com.hpe.oss.eventhandler.sduca.receiver.config.AppConfig]
[0m[0m15:13:03,483 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 219) JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
[0m[0m15:13:03,809 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 219) Mapped "{[/OSSreceiver],methods=[POST]}" onto public java.lang.String com.hpe.oss.eventhandler.sduca.receiver.OSSreceiver.postResponse()
[0m[0m15:13:04,071 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 219) Looking for @ControllerAdvice: Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Thu Aug 30 15:13:03 CEST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
[0m[0m15:13:04,188 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 219) Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1182 ms
[0m[0m15:13:04,189 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/sduca]] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 219) Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher'
[0m[0m15:13:04,189 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 219) FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization started
[0m[0m15:13:04,191 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 219) Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Thu Aug 30 15:13:04 CEST 2018]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
[0m[0m15:13:04,192 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 219) JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
[0m[0m15:13:04,220 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 219) FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization completed in 31 ms
[0m[0m15:13:04,239 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS018559: Deployed "sduca-consumer-listener-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war" (runtime-name : "sduca-consumer-listener-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war")
```

Here is the pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>sduca-consumer-listener</groupId>
    <artifactId>sduca-consumer-listener</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <!-- Telling to use jdk 1.7 -->
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- I am not using web.xml -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webappDirectory>/sduca</webappDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Using Spring 4 because of jdk 1.7 -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.18.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>


</project>
```

This one is the content of src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jboss-web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web>
    <context-root>sduca</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

There are three classes. 
AppInitializer.java
    /*
    This class configures the servlet of something
     */
    package com.hpe.oss.eventhandler.sduca.receiver.config;

```
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class AppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer{
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{ AppConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }
}
```

AppConfig.java

```
/*
This class is just for configuration and replace web.xml
Which is an old way of configuring I guess
 */

package com.hpe.oss.eventhandler.sduca.receiver.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.hpe.oss.eventhandler.sduca.receiver")
public class AppConfig {
}
```

And the controller: OSSreceiver.java

```
package com.hpe.oss.eventhandler.sduca.receiver;

import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@RestController
public class OSSreceiver {

    @RequestMapping(value="/OSSreceiver", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String postResponse()
    {
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps change `@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.hpe.oss.eventhandler.sduca.receiver")` to something shorter, like: `@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.hpe.oss")` in case it's not finding your components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change mapping to `/*` or `/sduca/*`

```
  @Override
  protected String[] getServletMappings() {
    return new String[]{"/*"};
  }
```